# How do I importing an existing S3 from ARN with CDK?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to import an existing S3 bucket by the arn using CDK.

So far code looks like,

```
class MyStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        s3_bucket_arn = CfnParameter(
            self,
            "S3_BUCKET_ARN",
            type="String"
        )

        s3_bucket = s3.Bucket.from_bucket_arn(
            self,
            "existing-bucket-from-arn",
            s3_bucket_arn.to_string()
        )
```

Next, when I bootstrap my account `cdk bootstrap --profile my-profile --parameters S3_BUCKET_ARN=arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-arn` this throws the follwing error,

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: ARNs must start with "arn:" and have at least 6 components: MyStack/S3_BUCKET_ARN
```

Comment: It should be `s3_bucket_arn.value_as_string`

Answer (score 2):

As per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html), I need to access the `value_as_string` attribute.

I updated my code to;,

```
    s3_bucket = s3.Bucket.from_bucket_arn(
        self,
        "existing-bucket-from-arn",
        s3_bucket_value_as_string
    )
```